# JDA returing null when getting guild by id

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, discord-jda

I am making Minecraft plugin, that will communicate with discord but when I try to get guild by id, it will return null.

```
jda = new JDABuilder(AccountType.BOT).setToken(token).build();
jda.addEventListener(new ReactionRecieveEvent(this));
jda.addEventListener(new CreateNewVoiceChannel(this));
jda.addEventListener(new DeleteEmptyChannel(this));
new VerifyCommand(this);
```

This is where I build JDA. Class VerifyCommand is command executor and I am trying to get the guild from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That way is deprecated, so use this way.

```java
jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token).build();
jda.addEventListener(new ReactionRecieveEvent(this));
jda.addEventListener(new CreateNewVoiceChannel(this));
jda.addEventListener(new DeleteEmptyChannel(this));
new VerifyCommand(this);
```

or you can use this way to improve readability

```java
jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(token)
    .addEventListener(new ReactionRecieveEvent(this))
    .addEventListener(new CreateNewVoiceChannel(this))
    .addEventListener(new DeleteEmptyChannel(this))
    .build();
new VerifyCommand(this);
```

You can see wiki for simple questions
https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki